# Spring Boot from Eclipse to IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, intellij-idea

I've been programming for a while in Eclipse now, but I have a new job and everything uses IntelliJ, so for my own projects I want to start IntelliJ as well now to get used to the shortcuts and what not. The Spring Boot application I have works perfectly in Eclipse, when I start it from there as well. I tried to start a new project in IntelliJ from the pom.xml. I have no idea what the problem is. Can anyone help me please? Below is the message I get when trying to start the main in the Spring Boot:

```
2017-06-10 17:35:23.288  INFO 6320 --- [           main] c.r.wave.RunescapesiteApplication        : Starting RunescapesiteApplication on MSI with PID 6320 (D:\website\runescapesite\target\classes started by Martijn Jansen in D:\website\runescapesite)
2017-06-10 17:35:23.290  INFO 6320 --- [           main] c.r.wave.RunescapesiteApplication        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-06-10 17:35:23.343  INFO 6320 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@80ec1f8: startup date [Sat Jun 10 17:35:23 CEST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-06-10 17:35:23.508  WARN 6320 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.runescape.wave.RunescapesiteApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer
2017-06-10 17:35:23.512 ERROR 6320 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Destroy method on bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory' threw an exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@80ec1f8: startup date [Sat Jun 10 17:35:23 CEST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404) [spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationListenerDetector.postProcessBeforeDestruction(ApplicationListenerDetector.java:97) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:253) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:578) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:554) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:523) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:968) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1033) [spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:555) [spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
at com.runescape.wave.RunescapesiteApplication.main(RunescapesiteApplication.java:17) [classes/:na]

2017-06-10 17:35:23.526 ERROR 6320 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.runescape.wave.RunescapesiteApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:180) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:308) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:228) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:270) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:686) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:524) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
at com.runescape.wave.RunescapesiteApplication.main(RunescapesiteApplication.java:17) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer
at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:163) ~[spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.retrieveBeanMethodMetadata(ConfigurationClassParser.java:374) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:308) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:244) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:197) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:166) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContext
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:152) ~[spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletContext
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
... 21 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

And here is the pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.runescape.wave</groupId>
<artifactId>runescapesite</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>runescapesite</name>
<description>Runescape website voor clan</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.wnameless</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-flattener</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: could you post your pom please?

Comment: As requested, pom added to post

Comment: Try adding servlet-api to your pom. The version should be coming from the parent pom or else try 2.3
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

Comment: I added it, but I'm still getting the same message. I'm trying to start the main class. Is that correct or is there in IntelliJ another way to start a Spring application?

Comment: Thanks. yes, its main. Lastly, try removing the provided tag for servlet-api and re-import the maven project.

Comment: Does it work with mvn bootRun?

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either, but I think I found the problem with it but doesn't know how to fix it. It says [FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM. Then a few links, also one to the company I work for. I can't connect to it (cause i'm not on their VPN at the moment) but can anyone tell me how I can fix this?

Comment: `provided` scope seems to be the problem.

Comment: That seems to work, awesome. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

I realize the question is almost a year old, but since no answers yet... I also have a Spring Boot (2.0.1) project which works in Eclipse but fails with the same exceptions you list in Intellij.  CrazyCoder's comment was the fix (so he should get the answer if he posts as an answer).

In Intellij, I went to File > Project Structure, then selected Modules, and went to the Dependencies tab.  I changed the scope of spring-boot-starter-tomcat from provided to compile.  I was then able to start the boot project from within Intellij.